# Remove vertical scroll bar from iframe tag that is nested in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

So I have a iframe tags nested in a Javascript, due to what I'm achieving I need to have it this way. Anyway, how do I remove the vertical scrollbars so that they don't show?

My JS code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#addHolidayLink').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr("href")
            var pagetitle = $(this).attr("title")
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; overflow: hidden;  noresize:noresize; scrolling: no; seamless: seamless;" src="' + page + '" width="100%;" height="100%"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                    title: 'Edit Employee',

                    resizable: true,
                    autoOpen:false,
                    modal: true,
                    hide: 'fade',
                    width:850,
                    height:595
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        });
    });
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Perhaps this can help: [previously answered question][1]
 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21296952/5152519

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the scrolling:no and the seamless: seamless from the style="" and add it to the actual iframe.

For example

```
<iframe scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" style="border: 0px; overflow: hidden;  noresize:noresize;" src="' + page + '" width="100%;" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Goodluck